# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Sorry, for same type of question. I saw so many post in SO for stage failure. But none of those were able to resolve my issue. So I'm posting it again.
I'm running in databricks,Runtime 7.3 LTS. I have a spark dataframe df2.While I'm running the command

```
df2.show()
```

I'm getting following error message. Can you help me to resolve the issue?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 231.0 failed 4   times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 231.0 (TID 6106, 10.52.98.16, executor 0): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file  dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet. A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/delta-intro#frequently-asked-questions
```

---

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-780007467828035> in <module>
 ----> 1 df2.show()

 /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
382         """
383         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 384             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
385         else:
386             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
1258 
1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
 61     def deco(*a, **kw):
 62         try:
 ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
 64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
 65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

 /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer,  gateway_client, target_id, name)
326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
329             else:
330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o804.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 231.0 failed 4    times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 231.0 (TID 6106, 10.52.98.16, executor 0): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet. A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/delta-intro#frequently-asked-questions
at   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:331)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:463)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:451)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at  org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$class.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:770)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at com.databricks.s3a.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:108)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:428)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:409)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:755)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:201)
at  com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.getFileStatus(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:295)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:452)
at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readFooter(CachingParquetFileReader.java:366)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.prepare(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:477)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:390)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:281)
... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
at   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2905)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3517)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2634)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2634)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3501)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3496)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:232)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:835)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3496)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2634)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2848)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:316)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file      dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet. A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/delta-intro#frequently-asked-questions
at   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:331)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:463)
at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:451)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at  org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper$class.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:   dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet
at   com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:770)
at   com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at  com.databricks.s3a.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:108)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2$$anonfun$getFileStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:756)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:428)
at  com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
at   com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:409)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:450)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:755)
at  com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.getFileStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:201)
at  com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.getFileStatus(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:295)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:452)
at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.readFooter(CachingParquetFileReader.java:366)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.prepare(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:477)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:390)
at   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:281)
... 14 more
```

Comment: This file is deleted from that location - Just check once dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/p_suggestedpricefornegotiation/part-00000-e64f3491-8afe-44a9-a55d-3495bc7a1395-c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: But I haven't deleted the file.

Comment: From where you are creating the DF ? Is that some hive table ?

Comment: @dsk, My objective is to remove some data from a delta table based on certain filtering  criteria . So, I'm creating this df2 from that delta table using select query to filter records. Then I'm deleting the delta table finally I will recreate my delta table using df2 with filtered data

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter such issues, they are mostly coz of the databricks cluster being backed up. Most of the times a cluster restart has helped me in fixing the issue.